# Better samba4 logging

Tags: samba4

My default logging conf in `smb.conf` for samba-4.3.0 is:

```
log level = 1
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
```

The good thing is:

- all samba logs is in the same directory;
- each service and workstation has a single log file.

But still it is not perfect: all the kerberos (and other) log end up in the same `log.%m` (verbatim).

Remote logging is not straightforward.

There are better ways to setup logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use samba audit to save log as you want. Please refer to http://a32.me/2009/10/samba-audit-trail/. I tested that work fine with samba4